# How to Make Profile picture like SnapChat?

Tags: ios, snapchat

I am using LLSimpleCamera .I am capture the image and just store the    image in array but its not look Good. ? Any other way to show capture image and looks like snapchat Profile.

Here is the code m using.

```
-(void)captureimages
{
  counter++;
  if (counter<4)
  {
 [self.camera capture:^(LLSimpleCamera *camera, UIImage *image,NSDictionary *metadata, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) 
    {
        animationView1.hidden = YES;
        [imageArray addObject:image];
        [self performSelector:@selector(captureimages) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0 ];
    }
     else 
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", error);
    }
}
exactSeenImage:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
    animationView.animationDuration=3;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [animationView startAnimating];
}
else
{
 animationView.hidden = NO;
    [self.camera.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.camera removeFromParentViewController];
    view1.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance. !

Comment: its just an overlay on actul profile picture

Comment: its not overlay..

Comment: i am  display images in a 4 way what i m capture in this